# Is this an artifact of graphing prime number ratios, or a relationship between twin primes?

Tags: prime-numbers, graphing-functions, twin-primes

I started with [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1719618/twin-primes-continued-research) about linking at least one twin prime with each prime. My approach is:

1. Give each prime two buckets.
2. Put each odd 3n in the second bucket of it's largest prime divisor.
3. Put it in the first bucket if (3n-4, 3n-2) are twin primes.
4. Prove that no first bucket is empty, or that the density drops slow enough.

**Edit:** Let
 $d(p, 3n) = 
\begin{cases}
1  &  p|n \wedge p \text{ is largest prime divisor}\\
0  &  \text{ otherwise }
\end{cases} \\
 t(p, 3n) = 
\begin{cases}
1  &  d(p, n) = 1 \wedge (3n-4, 3n-2) \text{ are twin primes}\\
0  &  \text{ otherwise }
\end{cases} \\ 
 \\ 
f(p) = \sum_{3n}^N {t(p, 3n)} \\
g(p) = \sum_{3n}^N {d(p, 3n)} \\
h(p) = \frac {f(p)}{g(p)} \\
$

When I graph $f(p)$, it's about what you'd expect:
*Not enough reputation to post link.*

And the graph of $g(p)$ is no surprise either:
*Not enough reputation to post link.*

However, when I graph $h(p)$ for $N = 20M, 30M, ..$ I get this:
(y = 5%, 10%, 15%; x = primes < 20000; color = N +10M)

[Ratio of 3pn twins to total 3pn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzaPp.png)
*Not enough reputation to post image inline.*

**Are these lines a result of my small sample size and ratio-similarity? Or is this a pattern in how twin primes are distributed?**

Comment: Impossible to understand. Try to simplify your question as possible, explaining your plot with a simple latex formula.

Comment: I added the math and brief description. click on the link to view the graph.

Comment: It is not clear what is $\sum^N$. There are infinitely many integers having $p$ as its largest prime factor ie. $\sum_n d(p,3n) = \infty$

Comment: N is the limit, why did you remove the limit in your example?? so the absolute maximum possible would be N/3, not $\infty$.

Comment: You meant $f(p) = \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^N d(p,3n)$ ..? In that case $f(p),g(p)$ depend on $N$. Also do you know the [twin prime constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime#First_Hardy.E2.80.93Littlewood_conjecture) ? It comes from a conjectured model and asymptotic distribution for the primes and twin primes.

Comment: Please read the question again, and either answer or don't.